# Scala - play2 config get section

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe, typesafe-config

I decided to try scala out with play2. I am trying to somehow get a config section out of application config. It looks like this (by section I mean whole mail part)

```
services: {
  rest: {
    mail: {
      uri: "xyz",
      authorization: {
        username: "xyz",
        password: "xyz"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigObject
import play.api.Play.current

val config: Option[ConfigObject] = current.configuration.getObject("services.rest.mail")
```

This gives `Some(SimpleConfigObject())` and trough there the only way I am able to actually get `mail` section and use it as a `ConfigObject` is trough

```
config.get.toConfig.getString("uri")
```

Or I can get the actual value with

```
config.get.get("uri").unwrapped().toString
```

Or for fun:

```
config.get.toConfig.getObject("authorization").toConfig.getString("username")
```

Either way it seems to me I am doing it overly complicated. Is there some easier way to get a section from config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this as an answer for future reference.

After another while of playing with the code I have found `parseResourcesAnySyntax` method which does exactly what I want and since I have my config split into multiple parts for separate environments (application.dev.conf, etc.) I can simply do

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import play.api.Play._

val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("application.%s.conf" format current.mode)
```

and then use

```
config.getString("uri")

// or

config.getString("authorization.username")

// or if I want to use part of it as another section

val section: Config = config.getConfig("authorization")
section.getString("username")
```

Of course, another viable alternative is using a wrapper as mister Stebel recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Since the config library has a Java API, it can feel a bit verbose using it from Scala. There are some Scala wrappers though that enable more compact syntax. See https://github.com/typesafehub/config#scala-wrappers-for-the-java-library.

Comment: Thanks, looking at them now